# Convert BitmapImage to System.Windows.Media.Brush

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, canvas

How would I convert a  BitmapImage to a `System.Windows.Media.Brush`?

I have a BitmapImage imaginatively called `bitmap`, and I have a Canvas (also imaginatively titled) `canvas`.

How would I set the value of `canvas` to the value of `bitmap`?

I've tried `canvas.Background = bitmap;`, but that didn't work: `image.Source = bitmap;` works for images, but not Canvases: and

`ImageSourceConverter imgs = new ImageSourceConverter();
                canvas.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, imgs.ConvertFromString(bitmap.ToString()));`

didn't work either.

All of these worked with images, however.

Maybe something with `bitmap.ToString()` would work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create an `ImageBrush` and use that as the background:

```
 ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
 ib.ImageSource = bitmap;
 canvas.Background = ib;
```

Comment: Wow... easy as copy-and-paste! Thanks!

Comment: Indeed. Just make sure you understand it ;)

Comment: 1) how to get height and width from ImageBrush, 2) how to apply gesture on ImageBrush ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
canvas.Background = new ImageBrush(bitmap);
```